# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: interaction is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)


@bot.command()
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Hello!")

bot.run('token')
```

I have tried to send a mesage by interaction but it doesen't work.
I get this error : `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: interaction is a required argument that is missing.`

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: How you are using the test command? with slash like `/test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering is because the `test` command is defined as a regular command using the `@bot.command()` decorator, but you're trying to use it as an interaction (slash command) by specifying the `interaction` parameter.

You have two options to fix this:

1. If you want to use the `test` command as a regular command triggered by a message, remove the `interaction` parameter from the command definition:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(content="Hello!")
```

In this case, the command will be triggered when a user sends a message starting with `$test` (assuming `$` is your command prefix).

2. If you want to use the `test` command as a slash command (interaction), you need to use the `@bot.tree.command()` decorator instead of `@bot.command()`:

```py
@bot.tree.command()
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Hello!")

bot.run('token')
```

In this case, the `test` command will be registered as a slash command, and users can trigger it by typing `/test` in the chat.